# What's the error with use of is statement in echo statement?

Tags: php, if-statement, syntax-error, echo

I've following statement:

```
<?php
echo "
            <div class='rbt'>
            ".($rebate_no != 0)."
            echo '</br><hr>';".
            <div style='overflow:auto' class='well'></div>";
?>
```

What's the error isn above code. I played a lot for single quotes and double quotes but still the error is not resolved. Please help me in this regard.

Comment: I can't think of a simpler piece of code to debug.... Just turning on PHP error reporting would have taken you less time than posting the question here.

Answer (score 1):

Use this below code,

```
<?php
echo "<div class='rbt'>".($rebate_no != 0)?"</br><hr>":"";
echo "<div style='overflow:auto' class='well'></div>";
?>
```

Comment: Can't we acheve in one echo statement instead of using two echo statements?

Comment: You can use the `,` in echo for print the two statements `echo "<div class='rbt'>".($rebate_no != 0)?"</br><hr>":"","<div style='overflow:auto' class='well'></div>";`

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
printf(
    '<div class="rbt">
        %s
        <div style="overflow: auto" class="well"></div>
    </div>',
    $rebate_no != 0 ? '<br><hr>' : ''
);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write all your code like that it will get sloppy better do it this way:

```
<div class="rbt">
<?php if(rebate_no != 0) { ?>
  <br /><hr>
<?php } ?>
  <div style="overflow:auto" class="well"></div>

echo "<div class='rbt'>".($rebate_no != 0) ? ."<br /><hr>". : ''."<div style='overflow:auto' class='well'></div>";
```

Comment: I want in echo statement itself. Can you do that?